# Filtering area through defined time period using Google Earth Engine?

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, iteration, function

I tried the following code in the Google Earth Engine through the various countries which have different dry season. But I cannot understand how to iterate the code. can anyone generate iteration using this code over any country of the world?

```
//clip boundary for each and every collection
var clipBoundary = function(image)
                        {
                          return image.clip(countries.filterMetadata("ADM0_NAME","equals","India"))
                        }
//create a time band for linear regression
var createTimeBand = function(image) {
   // in the linear regression output.
  return image.addBands(image.metadata('system:time_start'));
};

 var startdate = ee.Date('2017-12-01');
  var enddate = ee.Date('2018-05-31');
var collection = ee.ImageCollection('MODIS/006/MOD13Q1').select('NDVI')
                        .filterDate(startdate,enddate)
                        .map(clipBoundary)
                        .map(createTimeBand)
                        .select(['system:time_start', 'NDVI'])
                        .reduce(ee.Reducer.linearFit())
                        .select('scale');
 print(collection)
  Map.centerObject(collection, 6)
 Map.addLayer(collection)
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want to iterate over all the countries. Since your asset countries was not shared/accessible, I made the countries from the asset "USDOS/LSIB_SIMPLE/2017".

You can first get all the country names using:

```
// get a list of country names. Use "ADM0_NAME" in your case
var countryNames = ee.List(countries.aggregate_array('country_na'));
```

You can then map over those country names and get the scale from the reducer output using:

```
// map over the countries to get a image collection per country
var mappedCountries = ee.ImageCollection.fromImages(countryNames.map(function(country){
  country = ee.String(country);
  // clip the colleciton to the country
  var clippedCollection = collection.map(function(image){
    return clipBoundary(image, country);
  });
  // reduce image collection and get scale
  var scale = clippedCollection.reduce(ee.Reducer.linearFit())
                      .select('scale');
  return scale.set('country', country);
}));
```

Note I made the function you defined function instead of variables so you can put them at the bottom of the script. Also note I prefiltered the collection on you start and end date. [See the link](https://code.earthengine.google.com/ed2ca3958abfe3901358cb08901123b1)